# Getting which UIcollectionviewcell the textview im touching is in

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView and each cell has a UITextView. I'm trying to make it possible to delete the entire cell when long pressing the text in a TextView and selecting Delete from the context menu.

I know I can override Delete by overriding

```
func delete(_ sender: Any?) {//I want to delete cell from here}
```

and

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(delete(_:))
    {
        return true
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

I just don't know how to find the current cell I am in.

Comment: You can assign tag for UITextView by using indexPath.row and get cell by this this tag.

Comment: But how do I know which textview the context menu is in?

Comment: In `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, set `cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row`. In func `delete(_ sender: Any?) { let textView: UITextView = sender as! UITextView; indexPath.row = textView.tag . Just call delete collectionCell method }`

Comment: Problem here is that the sender is a UIMenuController, not UITextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 3 Solution:
So some people were close, but everyone led me down the right path almost. The solution doesn't exactly answer my question, but it could be combined with a gesturerecognizer to answer the question specifically.

So my solution is based on how my code is formatted and may need to be tweaked for anyone else.

First:
From the UICollectionViewCell subclass, where my textview is implemented of course, I overrode the built in delete function. From there is created a variable that is instantiated with with the cells superview, which is a UICollectionView. This allows me to get the indexPath for the cell. From there I also create a variable that is instantiated with the UIView for where my UICollectionView is located. From there I created a function inside my UIView that takes in a IndexPath and deletes the cell.

Inside UICollectionViewCell:

```
override func delete(_ sender: Any?) {
    let cv = self.superview as! UICollectionView
    let indexPath = cv.indexPath(for: self)
    let view = self.superview?.superview as! UIView
    view.delCell(indexPath!)
}
```

Inside UIView:

```
func delCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {/*code for cell removal here*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` set indexPath.row as tag of your UITextView. Then in your `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` or UITextView long press you can access the tag of UITextView which helps to find the current cell.

You can access current cell using this code:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: textview.tag, section: 0)
let yourCell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
```

I hope this will help you, Or you are experiencing any other problems, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Give tag to textfield which should be equal to current indexPath while adding cell to collection view. When long press listener is triggered, check the tag value and based on that, do you operation.

Answer (score -1):

func deleteSections(IndexSet)
Deletes the sections at the specified indexes.

func deleteItems(at: [IndexPath])
Deletes the items at the specified index paths

Comment: But how do I get the indexPath. I'm trying to all this from within override func delete(_ sender: Any?){}

Comment: Your sender is your indexpath. [indexPath.row]

Comment: Sender here is a UIMenuController

Comment: @EdricChen I'm sorry I'm confused. Aren't you asking how to determine self so you can send that message to UIMenuController to handle an event such as delete?

Comment: I am trying to override the built in context menu button Delete, the menu which opens after selecting text in the uitextview, and get the cell for which I opened that context menu in.